# How to efficiently create a solid colored background image with Ruby-Vips

Tags: ruby, vips

I want to create a solid colored background canvas of a given size, using the methods available with Ruby-Vips. Right now, I am able to do so, like this:

```
canvas = Vips::Image.black(600, 600).ifthenelse([0,0,0], [252, 186, 3])
```

However, it seems strange to have to create a black image, then apply color pixel by pixel in this way. Is there a better or a more efficient way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to match an existing image, you can use [`new_from_image`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-vips/2.0.17/Vips/Image#new_from_image-instance_method):

```rb
y = x.new_from_image [1, 2, 3]
```

Makes an image which copies most properties from `x`, but every pixel value is replaced by `[1, 2, 3]`.

The source for `new_from_image` shows how to make an image efficiently from scratch:

```rb
    def new_from_image value
      pixel = (Vips::Image.black(1, 1) + value).cast(format)
      image = pixel.embed 0, 0, width, height, extend: :copy
      image.copy interpretation: interpretation, xres: xres, yres: yres,
        xoffset: xoffset, yoffset: yoffset
    end
```

So:

- make a one pixel black image
- add the constant
- cast to the desired format (uint8, double, etc.)
- expand to the desired size
- set metadata like resolution, interpretation, etc.

Comment: Sure enough, I benchmarked that against the example from the post, and it's about 3.5 times as fast. Thanks!